# cannot see php header

Tags: php, header

I am teaching myself how to create a php header for a website and I cannot see my header or nav or footer when i try to preview it in a google chrome. Since I am new to this, I'm not sure if I am missing something blatantly important in my coding or something simple. Can someone look at my new php coding and tell me if I am doing it incorrectly? Index and header codes listed below.

**My header code is:**

```
 <!--==============================header=================================-->

    <div id="header">

        <div class="inner">

            <div class="meta-info">

            <div class="extra-wrap">

            <ul class="social-links">

            <li><a href="index.html">English</a></li>

            <li><a href="esp-index.html">Espa&#xF1;ol</a></li>

            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>



            <form id="main-search" action="search.php"  >

            <input type="text" name="search"  style="background-color:#CCCCCC" >

            <a class="search-submit" onClick="document.getElementById('main-search').submit()" ></a>
            </form>
            </div>


            <br><br><br><a href="supportus.html" class="button3">Donate</a>  <a href="apply.html" class="button4">Apply</a>     </div>

            <a class="logo" href="index.html"></a>        </div>

    </div>
```

----------End header code

---

**My index code is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Creative Minds International PCS</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="description" content="Your description">

    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">

    <meta name="author" content="Your name">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="site/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="site/js/script.js"></script>

    <script src="site/js/flashobject.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>

        <div class='aligncenter'><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg"border="0"></a></div>  

    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <script src="js/html5.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css"> 

    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

<!--

var image1=new Image()

image1.src="../slideshow3.jpg" 

var image2=new Image()

image2.src="../slideshow2.jpg"

var image3=new Image()

image3.src="../slideshow4.jpg"

var image4=new Image()

image4.src="../slideshow1.jpg"

//-->

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28106351-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

    </head>


<body id="page2">

<div class="main-bg">

<?php include('Includes/header.php'); ?>


<?php include('Includes/nav.php'); ?>    


        <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="flash">

        <div id="head">

        <div class="aligncenter"><img src="slideshow3.jpg"  id="slide" alt="Creative Minds Slideshow" width="990" height="450">   <script>

        <!--

        //variable that will increment through the images

        var step=1

        function slideit(){

        //if browser does not support the image object, exit.

        if (!document.images)

        return

        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

        if (step<4)

        step++

        else

        step=1

        //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds

        setTimeout("slideit()",6000)

        }

        slideit()

        //-->

        </script>             

        </div></div>

    </div>  

</header>

    <!--==============================content================================-->

    <section id="content">

        <div class="container_12">

            <div class="wrapper">

               <div class="grid_8" id="welcome" class="editable">

        <article class="a4">

                      <h4>Welcome to Creative Minds</h4>

                      <div class="wrapper">

                      <figure class="img-indent">                          </figure>



                          <p class="p2">                        </p>

                          <p class="p2">

                              <strong>Creative Minds International Public Charter School is a new, tuition-free school for children in Washington, D.C.</strong>  <br><Br>We are the only public school in the District of Columbia that offers the International Primary Curriculum, a highly engaging, diverse curriculum with project- and arts-based activities that foster creativity, self motivation, social and emotional development, and academic excellence. Our goal is to provide students with the foundational skills required for successful participation in a global society. <br><br>Our program’s unique combination of child-centered, international, and developmental approaches to education is based on extensive research into various aspects of schooling that have the greatest positive affects on academic achievement.

<br> <a href="programs.html">Read More</a><br><br>

                                                        </p>

                      </div>

                  </article>

                  <article class="a2">

                                        <div class="wrapper">

                        <div class="grid_4 alpha">

                            <div class="box-1">

                            <h4><a href="careers.html" class="button2">Careers</a> <a href="requestmoreinfo.php" class="button2">Request More Info</a> <a href="apply.html" class="button2">Apply</a></h4>

                                                                                    </div>

                        <div class="grid_4 alpha">

                            <div class="box-2">                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div></div>

                  </article>

               </div>

            <div class="grid_4"><div class="grid_6" id="newsandevents" class="editable">


                         <h4 class="hp-2">News and Events</h4>



The Enrollment Lottery took place on Tuesday, April 17, 2012.  Emails were sent to families of students who were selected through the lottery<br> on April 18, 2012.  Enrollment packets were mailed to your address on April 20, 2012.<br><br>

If your child is on the waitlist, you will receive a postcard in the mail indicating his/her number on the waitlist.  We will continue to move through our waitlists until October 2012 and contact you as spaces become available.<br><br>

FOR STUDENTS WHO WERE ADMITTED THROUGH THE LOTTERY, <strong>PLEASE REMEMBER MAY 14, 2012 IS THE DEADLINE</strong> FOR SUBMITTING YOUR CHILD’S ENROLLMENT PACKET TO ENABLE US TO RESERVE HIS/HER SPACE.  
<br><br>

<img src="site/images/guitar2.jpg" align="left" alt="Guitar Logo">              



                 </article>           


                                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div></section>

</div>

<?php include('Includes/footer.php'); ?> 

<div id="dialog6" class="disable_masking"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didnt see one bit of php in there

Comment: I only coded in: <?php include('Includes/header.php'); ?> and <?php include('Includes/nav.php'); ?>  into my index file. Am I missing something else?

Comment: what does var_dump(file_exists('Includes/header.php')) output?  Im guessing you have to paths wrong

Comment: Does your header.php page have any php in it?

Comment: Are you actually running a web server, or are you just attempting to load the file from your filesystem in Chrome?  View your page source - do you see the `<?php ?>` inside your source?  The PHP won't be parsed and included by the web browser alone - it must be done by a web server.

Comment: All I did was took out the header content from my index file, labeled it header.php and then used the <?php include('Includes/header.php'); function in my index file.

Comment: Try making header.php <?php echo '<div id=... etc'; ?> Note you will have to escape any single quotes.

Comment: @Michael, you are correct, I was just using my local filesystem. Will try your route. thanks!

Comment: @HannahHarris [Look into XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) for a quick start setting up a local web server.

Comment: Well, I got the majority of it to show up! It is just screwy and not line up correctly. At least I see parts of it. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: one last question regarding adding the php files to my indexpage. If you take a look at this live page...http://www.creativemindspcs.org/index3.php you'll see that my header and nav and footer are outside the box. I placed the include function in the exact spot where it was in the index file and it still looks wrong. Am I missing something special about placing an include file?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can make of it, is to check filename/directory case (upper-lower, etc.) and/or paths. Personally, I avoid mixing letter-case at all cost and make them all lowercase.

On some servers such as Unix/Linux, "**Includes**" with an uppercase `I` is not the same as "**includes**" with a lowercase `i`, since they use an explicit (file/folder) naming convention, so that could be your problem.